# Is "educate not exclude" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

The following is part of a *Huffington Post* article. There seems to be something missing between "to educate" and "not exclude" — or is this sentence correct?

> I believe the purpose of public schools is to educate not exclude children and to help identify and meet child needs, not make children serve adult convenience, self interest, and systems.（HP, 2014.9.26.）

Answer (score 3):

The sentence is awkward because it lacks parallel construction.  When using the infinitive form in one verbal phrase, "to educate", it  would be better to say "not to exclude" in the next phrase.  As the sentence progresses, she uses another infinitive form, "to identify".  The sentence does not run smoothly, but it does run on.

Comment: Would there also be a comma needed after educate?

Comment: Yes, I would say so.  The whole sentence could use re-drafting, it is headed in four directions at once.

Comment: I would say that there should be a comma before **and** after the words "not exclude" because they are a parenthetical expression.

Answer (score 0):

As @Theresa commented, the sentence would benefit from rewriting. In particular, it would be easier to understand if its main ideas were presented individually and rephrased where necessary. For instance:

> I believe the purpose of public schools is to educate children, not to exclude them. Its priority should be to identify and meet the needs of the children, and not to serve adult convenience, self-interest and systems.